# How to store HttpClient GET fetched data into a variable?

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient, angular-tree-component

My Backend over at `localhost:3000/gettreeview` returns a JSON object and it needs to be stored in the variable `nodes`. I tried to accomplish it with the code below but have failed:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-treeview-tab',
  templateUrl: './treeview-tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./treeview-tab.component.scss']
})
export class TreeviewTabComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private client: HttpClient) {  }
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
  /**
 * Handle Http operation that failed.
 * Let the app continue.
 * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
 * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
 */
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
  return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error); // log to console instead

    // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
    this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

    // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
    return of(result as T);
  };
}
 /**
   * Log a failed AviorBackend error.
   * @param message - message of the operation that failed
   */
  private log(message: string) {
    throw new Error(`AviorBackend: ${message}`);
  }


  // should be fetched from API
  nodes = [];
  options = {};
  ngOnInit() {

 //get JSON 
  const API_URL = 'localhost:3000/gettreeview';
  return this.client.get(API_URL, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    map((res: Response) => {
      this.nodes = res || {};
    }),
    catchError(this.handleError())
  );
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
Type 'Response | {}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  Type 'Response' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
```

**UPDATE**
my template.html:

```
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options" (click)="test()" class="list-area"></tree-root>
<div id="treeuserdata" class="content-area"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
this.client.get(API_URL, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
  (res) => { this.nodes.push(res) },
  (error) => { this.handleError(); }
);
```

You also need to remove the `return` as you aren't returning anything from the `ngOnInit()` hook.

Comment: `Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.` :/

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, new versions of Angular deserializes the content of a response into an object by default. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Hm, now I'm getting `The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.`

Comment: Because you are assigning `Object` to array type. You need to push to the array. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Hm, for some reason the treeview does not appear and there's no error message. Maybe it's not supposed to in OnInit in the first place?

Comment: I do not know how you populate the treeview. There are be no error messages because the data is being saved correctly but it might not be used correctly.

Comment: How do I debug this?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the structure of your response and the template. Include `console.log(res);` after the line `this.nodes.push(res);`. Open your browser console and post the screenshot here. Also include your template (.html) file in your question.

Comment: `console.log` prints out the proper Tree Structure. What's the problem with displaying it then?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by tree structure. Also the template shows you are using a component with selector ‘tree-root’. So I would need to see the template of that component to understand how the ‘nodes’ array is used.

Comment: I meant to say array with elements, which Chrome Devtools shows in its proper structure. Tree-root is the plugin's selector if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Could you please say what plugin?

Comment: I made a quick [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-component-u3gmlp-xpskrm) for your problem. It seems `tree-root` doesn't update the template with objects added later to `nodes` variable.

Comment: [Here](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/async-data-1) is an excellent example from their docs to use async data. If you could not get it working you need to open a new question, because the scope of this question has already been solved.

Comment: I accepted your answer. I also posted a new question I would be glad if you were to answer it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60450560/how-to-implement-this-angular-tree-component-async-data-code

Comment: I am currently not in a position to run Angular locally. However, I would say it would serve you better if you tried something on your own and posted your experience implementing your requirement. Then more people would be interested in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to subscribe to get the results

.json() is not required with new angular versions

```
return this.http.request(request)
  .pipe(map(res => res) // you can map to anything you want here)
  .subscribe(
    data => console.log(data),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('yay')
  );
```

Comment: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'.`

Comment: You're also missing a closing bracket